# Connecting and controlling my desktop with my laptop monitor using ubuntu.

Tags: laptop, monitor

I would like to know how to use my laptop as a monitor for my desktop. my laptop is running windows 7 and my desktop is running ubuntu 13.10. i do not have a monitor for the desktop.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what type of solution you were looking for? Are you trying to find a hardware connection to your laptop monitor or are you trying to pipe your desktop screen to a working laptop? Would your laptop be on?

Comment: I'm afraid the closest you may come is a remote desktop solution.  This however would mean you need a monitor temporarily on the desktop to install and setup the remote server.  I do this all the time using tightvnc on the win7 box and remote desktop viewer in full screen on the laptop but this isn't exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Rarely do laptops have HDMI input ports. Almost all laptops come with HDMI output port.

There are various converters like AV-to-USB, HDMI-to-USB, VGA-to-USB which could be used to connect the desktop through the USB port in laptop.